# Error: GaxiosError: Login Required... when I'm logged in

Tags: javascript, express, google-api, passport.js, gmail-api

I've been having a problem with pulling Gmail API. I have done all the steps for authentication but I'm stumped on a certain part: I'm getting this error: "GaxiosError: Login Required." while trying to pull: "gmail.users.messages.list", even after Google authentication.

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const passport = require("passport");
const cookieSession = require("cookie-session");
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const path = require('path');

require("./passport-setup");

const CLIENT_URL = "http://localhost:3000/inbox";
const passportSetup = require("./passport-setup");
const GoogleStrategy = require("./passport-setup").OAuth2Strategy;




const app = express();
const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1' });

app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.json());

app.use(
  cookieSession({
    name: "session",
    keys: ["key1", "key2"],
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World"));
app.get("/failed", (req, res) => res.send("Failed!"));

// GET /auth/google
//   Use passport.authenticate() as route middleware to authenticate the
//   request.  The first step in Google authentication will involve
//   redirecting the user to google.com.  After authorization, Google
//   will redirect the user back to this application at /auth/google/callback
app.get("/google", passport.authenticate('google', {
  scope: ['profile',
      'email',
      'https://mail.google.com/'
  ],
  accessType: 'offline',
  prompt: 'consent'
  
  }))
// GET /auth/google/callback
//   Use passport.authenticate() as route middleware to authenticate the
//   request.  If authentication fails, the user will be redirected back to the
//   login page.  Otherwise, the primary route function function will be called,
//   which, in this example, will redirect the user to the home page.
app.get("/google/callback", passport.authenticate("google", {
  successRedirect: CLIENT_URL, 
  failureRedirect: "/failed"
}))

app.get("/success", (req, res)=>{
  if(req.user) {
      res.status(200).json({
          success: true,
          message: "Login success!",
          user: req.user,
          cookies: req.cookies
  });
};
});


app.get("/inbox", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userId = 'me';
    const accessToken = req.user.accessToken; // Assuming the access token is stored in req.user

    const response = await gmail.users.messages.list({
      userId,
      maxResults: 10,
      auth: accessToken, // Include the access token in the request
    });

    res.json(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching Gmail messages:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to fetch Gmail messages" });
  }
});


app.get("/logout", (req,res)=>{
  req.logout();
  res.redirect(CLIENT_URL);
})
app.listen(5000, () => console.log(`Server running at port ${5000}!`));
```

passport_setup.js

```
const passport = require("passport");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

// Use the GoogleStrategy within Passport.
//   Strategies in Passport require a `verify` function, which accept
//   credentials (in this case, an accessToken, refreshToken, and Google
//   profile), and invoke a callback with a user object.
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: "insert client id",
      clientSecret: "insert client secret",
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:5000/google/callback",
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      return done(null, profile);
    }
  )
);
```

Here's the concentrated piece of code with me requesting gmail.users.messages.list with req.user.accessToken as the authentication method:

```
app.get("/inbox", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userId = 'me';
    const accessToken = req.user.accessToken;

    const response = await gmail.users.messages.list({
      userId,
      maxResults: 10,
      auth: accessToken, // Include the access token in the request
    });

    res.json(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching Gmail messages:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to fetch Gmail messages" });
  }
});
```

Comment: I ran your code and im getting TypeError: req.session.regenerate is not a function

Comment: I am also trying to make a NodeJS app that can grab some emails from my personal email. I also have the oauth2 flow working up til I try to use it. I get my tokens, can save them and get another session. When I try to fetch data with `await gmail.users.messages.list`, I get an error with gaxios saying Login Required.